# Are complex numbers equivalent to fractional negations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

Are complex numbers equivalent to fractional negations?

Examples:

Let's call $\operatorname{neg}$ the negation operator.

- $\operatorname{neg}23=(-23)$
- $\operatorname{neg}(-23)=23$
- $\operatorname{neg}\operatorname{neg}23 = \operatorname{neg}^2 23=23$
- $\operatorname{neg}^\frac{1}{2}23=23i$
- $\operatorname{neg}^\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{neg}^\frac{1}{2}23=\operatorname{neg}^\frac{1}{2}23i=23ii=(-23)$

Please, let me know if my question is wrong, obvious, repeated or if it is a valid but useless equivalence.

Comment: That's an interesting perspective. I would interpret your "fractional negation" operator as $\mathrm{neg}(a,z):=\exp(\pi ia)z$. But $\mathrm{neg}(1/2,1)=i$ is just a restatement of $i^2=-1$, so, sure, if you want to, view it like that

Comment: This is asking for opinions, because interpretations are pretty much open ended. MSE generally doesn't encourage this sort of questions, since there would not be a definite answer.

Comment: @Trebor I see. What SE site would be the right one?

Comment: Perhaps none. Stackexchange is different from forums.

Comment: @Trebor  I asked, because, someone might find it as a wrong interpretation, i.e., the fractional negation operator would not have a correspondence with the complex numbers. So, my question was more about a technical interpretation rather than an opinion.

Comment: @Trebor Sorry about the confusion. I changed the question to better reflect what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **yes**.

If (as @FShrike recommended in the question comments) we define a negation $\operatorname{neg}$ operator as:

- $\operatorname{neg} x=xe^{\pi i}$
- $\operatorname{neg}^n x=xe^{\pi i n}$

we will have an operator that:

1.- Applied to $x$ a positive integer $n$ number of times will negate it $n$ times

Examples:

- $\operatorname{neg}23=23e^{\pi i}=-23$
- $\operatorname{neg}\operatorname{neg}23=(23e^{\pi i})*e^{\pi i}=23e^{\pi i 2}=-(-23)=23=\operatorname{neg}^2 23$

2.- Applied in a fractional way will result in a corresponding complex number.

Examples:

- $\operatorname{neg}^\frac{1}{2}23=23e^{\pi i \frac{1}{2}}=23i$
- $\operatorname{neg}^\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{neg}^\frac{1}{2}23=\operatorname{neg}^\frac{1}{2}23i=23i e^{\pi i \frac{1}{2}}=23ii=-23=\operatorname{neg}^1 23=\operatorname{neg}23$

Therefore, with an operator like the one defined, complex numbers are equal to a fractional negation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).